# Issue in selecting search result on up and down key (asp.net page)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Want to select given suggestions on search using onclick and Key up & down function.

Form Screenshot:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBrHW.jpg)

The html code of form is as follow:

```
    <div class="search">
      <div>
        <i>
         <input name="ctl00$txtcat" type="text" value="Enter Search Key" id="txtcat" class="product" autocomplete="off" onfocus="if(this.value =='Enter Search Key') this.value = '';" onblur="if(this.value == '') this.value = 'Enter Search Key';" onkeyup="api_helper.callAjax();" style="color:#787878;">
        </i>
      </div>
    <div>
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$btnSearch" value="GO" id="btnSearch" class="btn_go" style="height:38px;width:61px;" />
               <div id="myDiv"><table width="100%"><tbody><tr><td class="select" onclick="api_helper.AddtoTaxtBox(this.innerHTML)">Accounting Services</td></tr><tr><td class="select" onclick="api_helper.AddtoTaxtBox(this.innerHTML)">Attorneys</td></tr><tr><td class="select" onclick="api_helper.AddtoTaxtBox(this.innerHTML)">Appliances</td></tr><tr><td class="select" onclick="api_helper.AddtoTaxtBox(this.innerHTML)">AC/Heating</td></tr><tr><td class="select" onclick="api_helper.AddtoTaxtBox(this.innerHTML)">American</td></tr><tr><td class="select" onclick="api_helper.AddtoTaxtBox(this.innerHTML)">Applicants </td></tr><tr><td class="select" onclick="api_helper.AddtoTaxtBox(this.innerHTML)">Automotive</td></tr><tr><td class="select" onclick="api_helper.AddtoTaxtBox(this.innerHTML)">ATM</td></tr><tr><td class="select" onclick="api_helper.AddtoTaxtBox(this.innerHTML)">Accessories</td></tr><tr><td class="select" onclick="api_helper.AddtoTaxtBox(this.innerHTML)">Asian</td></tr><tr><td class="select" onclick="api_helper.AddtoTaxtBox(this.innerHTML)">Allergy/Breathing Specialists</td></tr><tr><td class="select" onclick="api_helper.AddtoTaxtBox(this.innerHTML)">Apartment</td></tr><tr><td class="select" onclick="api_helper.AddtoTaxtBox(this.innerHTML)">Auto Parts</td></tr><tr><td class="select" onclick="api_helper.AddtoTaxtBox(this.innerHTML)">Accounting &amp; Finance</td></tr><tr><td class="select" onclick="api_helper.AddtoTaxtBox(this.innerHTML)">Advertising</td></tr><tr><td class="select" onclick="api_helper.AddtoTaxtBox(this.innerHTML)">Auto</td></tr><tr><td class="select" onclick="api_helper.AddtoTaxtBox(this.innerHTML)">Automotive</td></tr><tr><td class="select" onclick="api_helper.AddtoTaxtBox(this.innerHTML)">Architects</td></tr><tr><td class="select" onclick="api_helper.AddtoTaxtBox(this.innerHTML)">African</td></tr><tr><td class="select" onclick="api_helper.AddtoTaxtBox(this.innerHTML)">Asian</td></tr><tr><td class="select" onclick="api_helper.AddtoTaxtBox(this.innerHTML)">Auto Parts</td></tr><tr><td class="select" onclick="api_helper.AddtoTaxtBox(this.innerHTML)">Afghani</td></tr><tr><td class="select" onclick="api_helper.AddtoTaxtBox(this.innerHTML)">Aqeeqah</td></tr><tr><td class="select" onclick="api_helper.AddtoTaxtBox(this.innerHTML)">Accounting &amp; Finance</td></tr><tr><td class="select" onclick="api_helper.AddtoTaxtBox(this.innerHTML)">Automotive</td></tr><tr><td class="select" onclick="api_helper.AddtoTaxtBox(this.innerHTML)">Apartment</td></tr><tr><td class="select" onclick="api_helper.AddtoTaxtBox(this.innerHTML)">Automotive</td></tr><tr><td class="select" onclick="api_helper.AddtoTaxtBox(this.innerHTML)">Accupuncture</td></tr><tr><td class="select" onclick="api_helper.AddtoTaxtBox(this.innerHTML)">Auctions</td></tr></tbody></table></div>
```

Calling the Result using following script:

```js
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        if (typeof (api_helper) == 'undefined') { api_helper = {} }

        api_helper.doAjax = function (HandlerUrl, displayDiv) {
            var Req; try { Req = new XMLHttpRequest(); }
            catch (e) {
                try { Req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); }
                catch (e) {
                    try { xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }
                    catch (e) { return false; }
                }
            } Req.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (Req.readyState == 4) {
                    var d = document.getElementById(displayDiv);
                    d.innerHTML = Req.responseText;
                }
            }
            Req.open("GET", HandlerUrl, true); Req.send(null);
        }

        api_helper.callAjax = function () {
            var text = document.getElementById("txtcat").value;
            if (text != "") {
                var requestUrl = "Category_search.ashx?name=" + text;
                var displayDiv = "myDiv";
                api_helper.doAjax(requestUrl, displayDiv);
            }
        }

        api_helper.AddtoTaxtBox = function (txt) {
            var txtfinal = txt.toString();
            txtfinal = txtfinal.replace('&amp;', '&');
            document.getElementById("txtcat").value = txtfinal;
            document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = "";
        }
</script>
```

I need help to select displayed suggestion on click and key up & down. Selecting the input is set on onclick till now.

Comment: it looks like there is no logic at all for selecting a result in your code. what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have updated calling function in question

Comment: Provided code is not working

Comment: Can anyone provide me a proper solution for my question :(

Comment: I think the reason nobody is answering your question is that you expect someone to just write you an entire solution for a problem you are having without putting any effort into it. besides this ; your code does not have any example data, which may cause anyone looking at it to think it's too much work to figure it out, and they will just skip over your question.
Be sure to read this for help : https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: at least ; those are the two things keeping me from putting in the effort of writing an actual answer for this. You did not post this with the intent to learn anything, you posted it expecting us to do your work for you.

Comment: Haven't posted the entire code, just wanted to figure out how to do that. I have tried several tutorial on this thing but none was helpful.

Comment: If you can't help than please don't judge other.

Comment: There is a difference between can't and won't. we're here to help (that is, help you understand things about programming). we're not here to write your software for you. if you expect someone to write your software for you, you should pay them. you provide an incomplete example that shows zero effort on your part and expect us to fill in the blanks and add functionality to your program on demand. that isn't asking for help, that is trying to cheat on us, your employer and finally yourself.